# How to get an average between two columns to condense the rows by using SQL in Social Network Analysis (SNA)

Tags: sql, r, sqldf, sna

I have three columns: Sender, Receiver, # of Text Messages.

I need to condense the rows by getting the average of two columns.

So let's say Carol sends Jack 8 text messages, and Jack sends Carol 4 text messages, the result would be 6 messages between these two people.

See image below for better description.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADN05.png)

Comment: Please post your data as text, not images. Responders would have to type it all in if it is not text.  If mydata is your data frame then paste the output of `dput(mydata)` into the question or if that is very large `dput(head(mydata))`

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of doing this in SQL is something like:

```
select least(sender, receiver) as person1,
       greatest(sender, receiver) as person2,
       sum(num)
from t
group by least(sender, receiver),
         greatest(sender, receiver);
```

Some databases don't support `least()` and `greatest()`.  These can be replaced by `case` expressions.

```
select (case when sender < receiver then sender else receiver end) as person1,
       (case when sender >= receiver then sender else receiver end) as person2,
       sum(num)
from t
group by (case when sender < receiver then sender else receiver end), 
          (case when sender >= receiver then sender else receiver end);
```

Comment: thanks. It looks like SQLDF doesn't support least() and greatest(), would you be able to tell me how to do it using case expressions?

Comment: I didn't believe in God before this but then you answered my questions. Thank you!